# How to rotate UIImageView around a point?

Tags: uiimageview, transform, rotation, iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UIimageView rotate around a point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129324/uiimageview-rotate-around-a-point)

How to rotate UIImageView around a point?
I have already use those code but it seems useless

Compass2.layer.anchorPoint=CGPointMake(0, 0.5);/*I using this,but it can't rotate by :point even i change the coordinate in CGPointMake */

[Compass2 setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(temp1)];/* Compass2 is a UIImageView like below picture I want to rotate it around : point in image.

```
    ^
    |
    | 
    |
    :
    |
```